# Filter posts by multiple custom taxonomy terms using AND operator in REST API v2 (WordPress)

Tags: rest-api, multi-taxonomy-query

I've created a custom post type called 'events'. I've also created a custom taxonomy called 'event_categories' containing the 12 months of the year.

I am trying to get 'events' held in August AND (not OR) September (term IDs 41 and 42) using the following urls:

`/wp-json/wp/v2/events?event_categories=41,42`

`/wp-json/wp/v2/events?event_categories=41+42`

For some reason these urls return the same results and don't use the AND operator. They both use the OR operator and return events that are in either August or September.

I've also tried the following urls below but neither utilise the AND operator:

`/wp-json/wp/v2/events?filter[event_categories]=august,september`

`/wp-json/wp/v2/events?filter[event_categories]=august+september`

Comment: http://y-designs.com/blog/wp-api-multiple-taxonomy-query/

Comment: Thanks Inarilo, but I've already tried that guide and for some reason it doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: please post the code you are using based on that guide

Comment: appears to be a problem with WP https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-4-7-custom-taxonomy-filter-stopped-working/ rest_query_vars, has been removed. one of the commenters added their solution.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this inarilo! I followed some of the suggestions in the comments but it didn't make a difference. Their main problem at the time was that filter[event_categories] wasn't working at all. It's working for me but it's just not using the AND operator with multiple taxonomy values separated by ','. It could still be an issue with rest_query_vars but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: did you scroll down? there is an extensive code example to replace working with rest_query_vars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know the fix. I noticed that the plus sign (+) in the url arguments was automatically being stripped and converted into a space.

My arg values 'august+september' were becoming 'august september' after decoding. I found out that '%2B' is the code equivalent of the + symbol.

So, instead of using: `/wp-json/wp/v2/events?filter[event_categories]=august+september`

Use: `/wp-json/wp/v2/events?filter[event_categories]=august%2Bseptember`

Comment: `filter` has been removed from the REST API. ref: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/frequently-asked-questions/#what-happened-to-the-filter-query-parameter